# Change in linear momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, collision

Let A and B be to rigid blocks. A is stationary while B is moving with a velocity $u$. So if B collides with A. (These blocks are on a frictionless surface.)

1. What would happen after B collides with A, will they stick together and move with some uniform velocity why or why not.
2. If they stick together and start moving with velocity $v$. Then what we  do we          say that momentum is conserved (why?) and find $v$ 
   ( $m_1$= Mass of A and $m_2$ = Mass of B)

$$v=\frac{m_2 u}{m_1+m_2}$$

but we know energy is always conserved so

$$\frac12m_2  u^2= \frac12(m_1 +m_2)v^2 $$

both of them give contradictory result 
 I think this happened because I forgot to add the work  done on A and B but how    should I find it. How would we find $v$ using conservation of energy?

Comment: See [this recent question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254339/)

Comment: Can we consider that no energy is lost as heat and sound

Comment: In that case the two objects will *not* stick together and move off with the same final velocity.

Comment: if that happen then how can find v using conservation of energy

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that you have referred to energy conservation a couple of times in your question and comments.

So there is something that we should make *very* clear. Conservation of energy in general does *not* mean the conservation of any given kind of energy. Potential energy can turn into kinetic energy can turn into nuclear, chemical, thermal or acoustic energy or back again freely and at any time without violating the conservation of energy.

What you are asking for is the conservation of a particular class of energy (the kinetic energy relating to bulk motions of the objects in your problem), and that is *not* required by conservation of energy.

In fact, the conservation of that particular kind of energy only occurs in rare and special cases which we give the descriptor "elastic". It is only in *elastic* collisions that you expect 
$$ \sum \frac{1}{2}m_i v_i^2 = \sum \frac{1}{2} m_i u_i^2 \,,$
and the stick-together case that you describe is not one of these rare events (it is actually another fairly special case we describe as "completely inelastic").

So you have no-expcetation of bulk kinetic energy being conserved.

> General rules: momentum is conserved in *all* collisions, (bulk kinetic) energy is conserved only in elastic collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Energy is not conserved during an inelastic collision so you cannot find $v$ using conservation of mechanical energy concept.

Answer (score 0):

1. Without further information it is not possible to predict if the two bodies will stick together or coalesce.  This depends on the nature of the materials which come into contact, and the presence of any interlocking mechanism (such as used to couple carriages of a train).
2. Momentum is always conserved in collisions; kinetic energy is not always conserved.  Your 1st equation gives the correct result, the 2nd is incorrect.  If the collision is perfectly elastic (relative velocity of approach = relative velocity of separation) then you can use the conservation of kinetic energy.   When bodies couple together or coalesce, kinetic energy is not conserved.