# Are all bounces elastic?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, elasticity

Why a racket can hit everything, even things "apparently" inelastic?
Why something inelastic can be hitted? 
Can something inelastic bounce?
If there is, give me an example with their equations.

Comment: see this question and answers here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256468/

Answer (score 1):

There's no real dividing line between "elastic" and "inelastic."  Like many things in physics, its actually a continuous scale between them.

We say a collision is "elastic" when the conservation of energy can be used to predict the results of the collision.  If enough energy is converted into heat or deformations that we don't get good predictions out of the energy conservation laws, we call it "inelastic."

Note that our use of "elastic" is not the same as the use of "elastic" as a word to describe rubber bands.  Rubber bands do indeed tend to deform *elastically*, but so do solid metal balls.  As long as they return to their previous shape with minimal losses, we call them elastic.

When you study further, you find that there are not "elastic" and "inelastic" objects, but rather elastic and inelastic collisions.  All objects have an "elastic" phase when they are pushed on lightly, where they return to their original shape after you stop pushing on them.  Objects that we think of as "inelastic" have a very small elastic phase before entering a very long "plastic" phase where the deformations are permanent.  Other objects have a small elastic phase and then break, rather than deform.

I recommend looking at [stress-strain curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93strain_curve) if you really want to understand more.  They describe how real objects take stresses.  It's more complicated, but it describes quite a lot.  For example, you can see the difference between a "hardened" metal and an annealed one.

Comment: Thanks, i give you +1